# Conditional formatting for dates in Google sheets

Tags: google-sheets, date, conditional-formatting

I work at a language school and I have a column giving the students expected arrival date.

I want to set conditional formatting to:

**Highlight in red any date that is older than 1 week**

**Highlight in Green any date that is in the next 4 weeks in the future**.

This will show students who haven't turned up & also those coming in the next 4 weeks.

Comment: You can't do that without the use of Google Apps Script.

Answer (score 1):

With New Google Sheets please try Custom formula is:

1. `=today()-a1>7` with Background red and Range: to suit
2. `=and(A1-today()>0,A1-today()<28)` with Background green and same Range:
3. `=A1-today()>=28` with Background white and same Range: